# Pass (hidden) data with $location.url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting a server response on a request that includes the following: 
redirect_url
job_name

I'm using angular's `$location.url(redirectUrl)` to navigate to the redirect url, which may have query string parameters. I'd also like to pass it the job_name for use by the next state, but even the ugly solution of tacking it onto the search params (with `$location.url(redirect_url).search(job_name)` doesn't work if `redirect_url` already HAS search parameters.

How can I pass data to a new state if I don't have the state's name, only the url? Do i have to parse it out?

Comment: The `$location` service was designed so that one can chain method calls. So that we can avoid having our answers ridiculed as "ugly", explain why you describe doing chains of method calls as "ugly".

Comment: I see that it's possible to pass hidden data between states using `state.go` with the `params` object, which I find less "ugly" than putting it on the URL in this case.